# How to create set Laravel schedule for each hour 15 minutes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

I need to run some data update functions each hours 15 minutes. For example:

- 12:15
- 13:15
- 14:15
- 15:15

How to create schedule for it? I tried something like `$schedule->command('stats:refresh')->hourly()->at(':12');` but didn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like `$schedule->command('stats:refresh')->cron('15 0-23 * * * *')`

Cron uses 5 asterisks as arguments. I've made a pull request, because I thought there is a mistake in Laravel documentation:
https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/2166

But here's answer from main Laravel developer:

> There is an optional 6th "year" argument available:
>   http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

If you click the last link, you'll see description of which one of the six asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$schedule->command('command')->cron('* * * * *')
```

Every **star** from left to right refers to

> - minute (0-59)
> - hour (0-23)
> - day of month (1-31)
> - month (1-12)
> - day of the week (0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday)

please take look at : 
http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/practical-laravel-using-cron-jobs-in-laravel/

Comment: `->cron()` uses 6 asterixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
...
$schedule->command('your:command')->everyFiveMinutes();
...
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey it should be

```
  $schedule->command('stats:refresh')->cron('15 0-23 * * *')
```

instead. If you add 15 0-23 to your asterisks it makes 6 instead of 5.

Comment: It seems Laravel uses 6 asterisks. Please read my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$schedule->command('command')->cron('15 * * * *')
```